# Donde encuentro la Documentacion de Angular 4.4.6

Tags: angular

Necesito la documentacion de `Angular 4.4.6` ya que la que muestran en la [pagina de Angular](https://angular.io/docs) es la de `Angular 5.0.0`.
Si alguien sabe donde encontrarla compartela.

Comment: visita esta pagina te puede ayudar mucho en lo que estas buscando https://angular.io/

Answer (score 2):

> Aquí la documentación de la 2: https://v2.angular.io/docs
>
> Aquí la documentación de la 4: https://v4.angular.io/docs

Comment: Otro enlace en gihub es: https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/aio/content